# Wordpress search page pagination displaying but not functional

Tags: wp-query, pagination, search

I have a search page with pagination, that is displaying the correct number of pages, however it the links seem to be forwarding to the 404 page.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$search_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 2,
    's'                 => get_search_query(),
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'paged'             => $paged,
);
$search = new WP_Query($search_args);
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$pagination_args = array(
    'base'      => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
    'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'mid_size'  => 2,
    'total'     => $search->max_num_pages
);

echo paginate_links($pagination_args);
```

Any help as to why these links might be broken would be a huge help!

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a custom query for the search page?

Comment: No reason, other than I'm new to this, and couldn't work out another way of doing it. If you have a better recommendation, please let me know!

Comment: When you create templates following the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) the main query, whose posts you loop through with `have_posts()` and `the_post()` (without `$search->` or anything like that) will have the correct posts already in it. Then you can use functions like `paginate_links()` without needing to specify any of the arguments.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't using `have_posts()` and `the_post()` mean that you wouldn't be able to give loop a search query from an input form?

Comment: If you use the standard WordPress search form, with `get_search_form()` or the widget, then you will be taken to `/?s={search term here}`. On that page the main query will be populated with results for that search. The template that's loaded will be based on the hierarchy (so search.php if it exists, otherwise index.php).

Comment: @JacobPeattie thank you. That's worked a treat. I don't know why I didn't think of that!
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided in the comments:

```
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$pagination_args = array(
    'base'      => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
    'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'mid_size'  => 1,
    'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages
);
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):
        the_post();
        //individual search result
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo paginate_links($pagination_args);
endif;
```